# how to migrate postgresql data from linux to windows

Tags: migration

i don't know how to migrate pgsql db from linux machine to windows machine.

I know how to take backup in linux machine using pg_dump but please tell me how to migrate from linux machine to windows machine.

Comment: I'd assume pg_restore runs on windows?

Comment: pg_restore will definitely work with db backup taken from linux machine????

Comment: lucky guess on my part. So... where's the problem? This looks like something you should try, and edit the question if you have further issues, and if not, post your own answer too.

Comment: here, i don't have testing machine and i need to restore 10 years old database backup..... so i need to do without any testing.....

Comment: you can create a db and try it to migrate windows according to advices. If you success, you have nothing to be afraid of. Also don't remove the db on linux until you are sure that you have migrated it without any problem.

Comment: Yes xxlali and Journeyman Geek thanks for your advice.  Today i tried importing by creating db in pgadmin III in windows and it's working.  Here are the ways how i execute the command:  By referring this URL (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736345/export-and-import-table-dump-sql-using-pgadmin) i tried and it's working....